# Rails 6 ActionText isn't working on Heroku (undefined method 'rich_text_area_tag')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

I am using ActionText to edit a paragraph and it works perfectly locally but when I deploy it to Heroku the page which has the form with rich_text_area it throws an error saying undefined method rich_text_area_tag even though I followed the rails guide. I thought I needed to configure Active Storage on production but that's not the case.

Here is what I am getting in Heroku's logs:
`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'rich_text_area_tag' for #<#<Class> Did you mean?  rich_text_area)`

```
<%= f.label :something, class:'label' %>
<%= f.rich_text_area :something %>
```

Comment: Your error says `undefined method 'rich_text_area_tag'`, but your code only have `rich_text_area`. Did you update it with just `f.rich_text_area`?

Comment: @allenbrkn thanks for your comment, I have it in the code as `f.rich_text_area` but I don't know why does it add **tag**, if you mean I should delete `:something` that will cause error.

Comment: Did you try running commands like `heroku run bundle exec rake db:migrate`, `heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile` after deploying?

Comment: @allenbrkn I tried both of them but nothing changed still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you run `heroku run rails -v` and `heroku run ruby -v` and see if Heroku is using your preferred Rails/Ruby version. Most of the time it will use properly, but just in case. Also, can you update your complete `form` code?

Comment: @allenbrkn Rails version on Heroku is `Rails 6.0.0` and Ruby version is `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]`

The form code here:
`<%= form_with(scope: chapter, url: chapter_path(chapter), method: "put", local: true) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :something, class:'label' %>
<%= f.rich_text_area :something %>
<% end %>`

Comment: Don't know what's causing the error. But can you try changing `scope: chapter` to `scope: :chapter`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found this online, and it was helpful for me:

https://github.com/JoeWoodward/spree_helper_issue

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but it's a temporary workaround.

SOLUTION:

In `application_controller.rb` enter the following:

```
require 'action_text'

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper ActionText::Engine.helpers

  ...
end
```

Docs for `helper`: https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper

Comment: Thanks @Violeta I added `require 'action_text'` and `helpers ActionText::Engine.helpers` in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` as it is the in link

Comment: Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Work like a charm, with small change: ```helper ActionText::Engine.helpers``` (no "s") I believe it's a typo :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that you have this line in config/application.rb:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

If it's a rails 6 app `action_text/engine` should be loaded.

If it doesn't it's possible taht zeitwerk is not loaded. This happens when you have a rails 5.2 app that was updated to rails 6.

In the same file (config/application.rb) you have to change config.load_defaults to 6.0:

```
config.load_defaults 6.0
```

If you want to know what happens in the background take a look at [this link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/66cabeda2c46c582d19738e1318be8d59584cc5b/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L74) on line 125.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at it, so I checked `config/application.rb` I have these two lines `require 'rails/all'` and `config.load_defaults 6.0` the only solution which worked for me is that I had to add `require 'action_text'` but I ended up adding trix-editor tag manually. @TopperH

Comment: Are you for some reasons not using zeitwerk?

Comment: I have `config.autoloader = :zeitwerk` in `config/application.rb` @TopperH

Answer (score 1):

To avoid cluttering the `ApplicationController` code, you can use an initializer:

i.e. add a new file `config/initializers/action_text.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
  include ActionText::ContentHelper
  include ActionText::TagHelper
end
```

Inspired by [p8](https://github.com/p8)'s comment in a closed Rails [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37672#issuecomment-607143920).